# How to say "it gives an opportunity" in a word?

Tags: word-choice

The phrase is often used in a written speech. E.g.:

- Everybody needs an education. It gives you an opportunity to have a good job and to succeed in life.

How to rephrase that:

- It enables you...
- It lets you...
- It allows you...

None seems good enough. How can you say it better?

Comment: *helps*, *facilitates*, ...

Comment: .... _positions_ [complex catenative with to-infinitive] [M-W: _The company is positioning itself to take advantage of a new market._
_The shortstop was positioned well to make the play._ ]

Comment: _It promises a promising opportunity._

Answer (score 6):

How about *it **[empowers](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/empower)** you*?

> to give ability to; enable; permit

The term has a fairly strong connotation, if that is what you wish to convey.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idiom ["open the door to (something)"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20the%20door)

> *Everybody needs an education. It opens the door to success.*

Comment: As much as I like the phrase, it is not in one word !

Comment: @Alexandre Cassagne It's still a valuable contribution given that the author is asking for advice on how to "rephrase" or "say it better." Thanks for pointing it out though! :)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe "It provides/opens you..."!?

Comment: Do you mean "opens you up to" or similar? In any case, a good answer will explain and give sources. Why do you think these words are correct? Can you give definitions and/or usage examples?